# In an mvc app, how do you fallback to default IHttpControllerSeelector if the custom one doesn't match a url path

Tags: asp.net-web-api-routing

I read this article to try and created a versioned webapi controller using the namespace:

> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/03/08/using-namespaces-to-version-web-apis.aspx

I don't want to break existing routes, so it's pretty important for me to be backward compatible.

and it makes it sound trivial in the end-note to use the default one if the routes don't match, but it's not trivial to me. If you can help that would be awsome.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the [Code](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/dd207952fa86#Samples/WebApi/NamespaceControllerSelector/NamespaceHttpControllerSelector.cs) referred to in the [Article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/03/08/using-namespaces-to-version-web-apis.aspx), you could do this in the SelectController method:

```
public HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    IHttpRouteData routeData = request.GetRouteData();
    if (routeData == null)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }

    // Get the namespace and controller variables from the route data.
    string namespaceName = GetRouteVariable<string>(routeData, NamespaceKey);
    if (namespaceName == null)
    {
        DefaultHttpControllerSelector selector = new DefaultHttpControllerSelector(_configuration);
        return selector.SelectController(request);
    }

    // ... remaining code from article
}
```

When the route does not contain a version parameter, create an instance of the DefaultControllerSelector and return the value from it's SelectController method.